# How to pull files and only override conflicts

Tags: git, github

How can I pull down a git and have it overwrite my local project ONLY where conflicts are found?

E.g. I have many folders / files in my local project that are not on the git project and never will be.

Ok... here is the full scenario.

I used DaftMonk generator to create a fullstack boilerplate:
https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

I then edited the boilerplate and created my app.

Now, I want to share my code on git, for colleagues to start developing on - BUT, daftmonk generator has added several of its folders to gitignore file (node modules / dist etc). As its not good practice to check these in (Plus, it throws a wobbly since the paths are too long in node modules folder).

So, I am trying to get the code working elsewhere. However, the code in the git needs all the node modules etc to work... So, I have made another install of daftmonk and am now wanting to place my git code on top of this.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please explain your scenario more clearly. Do you mean merge conflicts or changes?

Comment: Have explained scenario in more detail now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a `git pull` should do the right thing, as long as you haven't done git add on the files you don't want in to have under git.  I suggest putting the names of those files in a .gitignore.

If you are running into a specific problem with using `git pull`, you should ask about *that*.

I don't know much about DaftMonk, but if it generates a lot of boilerplate that shouldn't be committed, then it seems likely that is part of the build/development process you need to manage.  Meaning, you would call DaftMonk *after* you clone your repo.  Possibly with a Makefile, or whatever build tool is common in your language of choice.

The idea is that generated files that can change because of a change in configuration/other source should not be modified by hand, but instead be regenerated as needed.  Therefore, if DraftMonkey is doing such a generation, you need to incorporate that into your process.

Comment: Hi Daniel - have added clarification now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you do not yet have the git repository on your local machine, and you want to clone it, overwriting those files on your local machine that also exist in the repo. If so, the easiest way to do it would be to clone the repo into a *new* directory, then copy that directory to your existing one.